# Where to add child to?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm developing a small game in Swift and there's something I've been struggling with. In this custom class, I am using `touchesBegan` method, and within this method I want to create an SkNode. This is my code:

```
class TouchableSpriteNode : SKSpriteNode

    {


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        self.removeFromParent()
        let delay = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(200)))*Int(NSEC_PER_SEC)/100
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            let random2 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.width))
            let random3 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.size.height))

            div.position = CGPoint(x: Int(random2), y: Int(random3))
            self.addChild(div)
        }
        }
}
```

the problem is, I can't get it displayed on the screen, because I get an error which says that you can't that child, because it's his own parent(it's complicated), the thing I want know is how could I say add the child to the scene, not to this skspritenode?
Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Can you post the "complicated" error? :)

Comment: The error isn't complicated, it is complicated why the class is the parent of the SKSpriteNode..

Comment: Where are you actually declaring `div`? If you want to add multiple instances of `div`, the declaration should be inside your function. Otherwise, it'll try to re-add an already-added node (rather than adding a new instance of the node), resulting in an error. Is this what's happening?

Comment: Yeah I get what you're saying, but that's not the problem here. The problem is when I do self.addChild(div) then it tries to add it to GameScene.TouchAbleSpriteNode and I want it added to GameScene. In didMoveToView, self means GameScene, but in this class self means GameScene.TouchAbleSpriteNode

Comment: add it to `self.parent`!?

Comment: when I do `self.parent!.addChild(div)` it gives an error for founding nil while unwrapping

Comment: self.parent is nil, how could this fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write this without testing, but it should work: right before you call `self.removeFromParent()` add the line `parent = self.parent`; then, use `parent.addChild(div)` instead of `self.addChild(div)`.

Did that do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

This won't be the answer you're looking for, but I'm not sure you can add a node to your view controller from within another class. For this situation, I'd recommend implementing `touchesBegan` in the viewcontroller, and detecting inside that function whether the touch is happening on your touchable node. Then you can easily add and remove objects from the view.